# How can I customize some of a UITableView's cell heights, but leave others as defaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

To specify cell heights of a table view we use the delegate method,

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

However this method asks cell height of every row, what can I do if I want some of them to be defaults?

For cell height we may return `UITableView#rowHeight` for those default rows inside the delegate method, **but I also want some (not all) of the section headers/cell to be customized**.

But I am not able to get the defaults from the table view, especially for grouped style table view, anyone has a solution?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm sorry for not making it very clear.  In fact, cell height is not the only one that I want to partially customize, but also something else like section header (there may be more, like delete button style, etc.).

Is there solution without mimicking default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want default behavior in all cases, you'll still have to mimic default behavior in the non-specialized cases.

for headers, you will still have to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and therein, you will have to answer the default height for those headers you do not wish to change, and the specialized header height for those you do want to change.

similarly, in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*);
```

you will still have to mimic default behavior for those cells you do not wish to change.

you could accomplish all of this with storyboard if you want:  create specialized cells with unique identifiers for each, and then return the cell heights that go with them.  if you take this route, then you may be able to get away with just using dequeueReuaableCellWithIdentifier and using the height value for that identifier.  just use a unique cell identifier with a height that's appropriate for each cell you're thinking of.

Comment: Thanks.  I will take your answer.  That's ALL what I want to know: is there an easy way, YES no NO.

Answer (score 1):

The default height of cell is 44 .. so you can return it when your condition is not satisfied ..

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      if (YOUR_SPECIFIC_CONDITION) {  
     return 180.0;
     }
     return 44.0; 
 }
```

May this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section==0) 
    {  
        return 180.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 44.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for cell height, but how about something else like section header view?